# iText7 HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf how to scale text to fit within div container

Tags: c#, html, css, itext, itext7

I have different areas in different fixed sizes which contains some text.

What I want to achieve now is to show the text in the largest size possible with or without linebreaks.

For example: The text is within a container of the size:
`7x1.8cm`

Now I want to make the text as large as possible for this container. When the text is larger, the size should automatically shrink down.

Is there any way to achieve this using iText7 compatible CSS and HTML?

Basic example:

```css
.description {
width: 7cm;
height: 1.8cm;
}
```

Then for example this two variants

```html
<div class="description">Hello World</div>
```

```html
<div class="description">Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

I already tried using `vw` units and the `clamp` function but both of these are not recogonized by iText7.

As a workaround I'm generating a new PDF in the required size and putting calculate the size of it using this class. Which the value will then be divided by 12 to get it in rem. But there must be a better solution for this.

```cs
public static class IText7Test
{
    public const int DPI = 72;
    public const float INCH_FAKTOR = 2.54f;
    public static float CreatePdf(string dest, string text, float width_in_cm, float height_in_cm)
    {
        //using var stream = new MemoryStream();
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        float width = width_in_cm / INCH_FAKTOR * DPI;
        float height = height_in_cm / INCH_FAKTOR * DPI;

        Rectangle myPageSize = new(width, height);
        pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(new PageSize(myPageSize));
        Text lineTxt = new Text(text);

        Rectangle lineTxtRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

        Div lineDiv = new Div();
        Color bgColour = new DeviceRgb(255, 204, 204);
        Paragraph linePara =
          new Paragraph()
            .Add(lineTxt)
            .SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER)
            //.SetBorder(new DottedBorder(1))
            .SetBackgroundColor(bgColour)
            .SetMargin(0)
            ;
        lineDiv.Add(linePara);

        // 10 is the font size that is definitely small enough to draw all the text
        float fontSizeL = 10;

        // 20 is the maximum value of the font size you want to use
        float fontSizeR = 20;

        Canvas canvas = new(new PdfCanvas(pdfDocument.AddNewPage()), lineTxtRect);

        // Binary search on the font size
        while (Math.Abs(fontSizeL - fontSizeR) > 1e-1)
        {

            float curFontSize = (fontSizeL + fontSizeR) / 2;
            lineDiv.SetFontSize(curFontSize);
            
            // It is important to set parent for the current element renderer
            // to a root renderer.
            IRenderer renderer = lineDiv.CreateRendererSubTree().SetParent(canvas.GetRenderer());

            LayoutContext context = new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(1, lineTxtRect));

            if (renderer.Layout(context).GetStatus() == LayoutResult.FULL)
            {
                // we can fit all the text with curFontSize
                fontSizeL = curFontSize;
            }
            else
            {
                fontSizeR = curFontSize;
            }
        }

        // Use the biggest font size that is still small enough to fit all the
        // text.
        lineDiv.SetFontSize(fontSizeL);
        canvas.Add(lineDiv);
        pdfDocument.Close();

        return fontSizeL;
    }
```